# How to run a node function before a command call

Tags: node.js, command-line, cross-platform

I have a simple function that is installed via:

```
npm i -g my_func
```

It contains a single function which determines some information (asynchronously) from the arguments given to the command and then prints out some information to the console.

I'm trying to get it to run as a hook before the execution of an actual command.  For instance, my code looks similar to:

```
async function my_func(items) {
  console.log(items)
}

program
  .arguments('<param> <package> [packages...]')
  .action((param, package, packages) => { my_func([package].concat(packages) })
```

When a user runs, say:

```
some_command param example
```

I would like it to run the function, but I'm not entirely sure how.  Is there a way to overwrite such functions which doesn't interfere with their normal run?  Something similar to:

```
let oldLog = console.log

console.log = async () => {
  await some_func()
  oldLog(arguments)
}
```

Comment: You want to hook into every possible command ?

Comment: @Malice Sorry, no, I just want to hook into one command (in this case `npm`).